# How can my android app draw a line or tracks of my movements with gps on google map

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, tracker

I'm developing an android app that can trace the users locations and movements, using GPS and draw and save a line or the tracks that can be sent to a receiver who can open and see the saved tracks on Google map.

I already have a working code that can send the location but the receiver can only see the single position where the user sent from with a marker.

But I want it to track the movement and send so that the receiver can see all the places the user went when the app was on.

I would be really grateful if anyone can help me with this.

This is the code, @Ranjith or if anyone can help me detect the problem here. My tracks/lines are still not drawing

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.Projection;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.StreetViewPanorama;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener,
        OnMapReadyCallback {

    /**
     * The desired interval for location updates. Inexact. Updates may be more or less frequent.
     */
    public static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 10000;

    /**
     * The fastest rate for active location updates. Exact. Updates will never be more frequent
     * than this value.
     */
    public static final long FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS =
            UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS / 2;

    // Keys for storing activity state in the Bundle.
    protected final static String REQUESTING_LOCATION_UPDATES_KEY = "requesting-location-updates-key";
    protected final static String LOCATION_KEY = "location-key";
    protected final static String LAST_UPDATED_TIME_STRING_KEY = "last-updated-time-string-key";

    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Location mCurrentLocation;

    /**
     * Tracks the status of the location updates request. Value changes when the user presses the
     * Start Updates and Stop Updates buttons.
     */
    protected Boolean mRequestingLocationUpdates;

    protected Button mStartUpdatesButton;
    protected Button mStopUpdatesButton;
    protected Button mSendPositionButton;
    protected TextView mLastUpdateTimeTextView;
    protected TextView mLatitudeTextView;
    protected TextView mLongitudeTextView;

    /**
     * Stores parameters for requests to the FusedLocationProviderApi.
     */
    protected LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    /**
     * Time when the location was updated represented as a String.
     */
    protected String mLastUpdateTime;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        // Locate the UI widgets.
        mStartUpdatesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_updates_button);
        mStopUpdatesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop_updates_button);
        mSendPositionButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_position_button);
        mLatitudeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitude_text);
        mLongitudeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitude_text);
        mLastUpdateTimeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.last_update_time_text);

        mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;
        mLastUpdateTime = "";

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        mMap = mapFragment.getMap();

        // Update values using data stored in the Bundle.
        updateValuesFromBundle(savedInstanceState);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

        createLocationRequest();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);
    }

    /**
     * Implementation of {@link LocationListener}.
     */
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        /**

        if (location.distanceTo(mCurrentLocation) > 10)
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),
                    location.getLongitude())).title("Marker"));

        mCurrentLocation = location;
        mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        updateUI();
        Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.location_updated_message),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         */
    }

    public void handleGetDirectionsResult(ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoints) {
        PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(15).color(Color.RED);
        Polyline routePolyline = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < directionPoints.size(); i++) {
            rectLine.add(directionPoints.get(i));
        }
        if (routePolyline != null){
            routePolyline.remove();
        }

        routePolyline = mMap.addPolyline(rectLine);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        if (mCurrentLocation == null) {
            mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
            mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        }

        updateUI();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        // Do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        // Do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
        Toast.makeText(this, mCurrentLocation.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Return false so that we don't consume the event and the default behavior still occurs
        // (the camera animates to the user's current position).
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Sets up the location request. Android has two location request settings:
     * {@code ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION} and {@code ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}. These settings control
     * the accuracy of the current location. This sample uses ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, as defined in
     * the AndroidManifest.xml.
     * <p/>
     * When the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION setting is specified, combined with a fast update
     * interval (5 seconds), the Fused Location Provider API returns location updates that are
     * accurate to within a few feet.
     * <p/>
     * These settings are appropriate for mapping applications that show real-time location
     * updates.
     */
    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();

        // Sets the desired interval for active location updates. This interval is
        // inexact. You may not receive updates at all if no location sources are available, or
        // you may receive them slower than requested. You may also receive updates faster than
        // requested if other applications are requesting location at a faster interval.
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

        // Sets the fastest rate for active location updates. This interval is exact, and your
        // application will never receive updates faster than this value.
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

    public void sendPositionButtonHandler(View view)
    {
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://maps.google.com/?q=" +
                mCurrentLocation.getLatitude() + "," + mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
    }

    /**
     * Handles the Start Updates button and requests start of location updates. Does nothing if
     * updates have already been requested.
     */
    public void startUpdatesButtonHandler(View view) {
        if (!mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            mRequestingLocationUpdates = true;
            setButtonsEnabledState();
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles the Stop Updates button, and requests removal of location updates. Does nothing if
     * updates were not previously requested.
     */
    public void stopUpdatesButtonHandler(View view) {
        if (mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;
            setButtonsEnabledState();
            stopLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Ensures that only one button is enabled at any time. The Start Updates button is enabled
     * if the user is not requesting location updates. The Stop Updates button is enabled if the
     * user is requesting location updates.
     */
    private void setButtonsEnabledState() {
        if (mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            mStartUpdatesButton.setEnabled(false);
            mStopUpdatesButton.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            mStartUpdatesButton.setEnabled(true);
            mStopUpdatesButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Requests location updates from the FusedLocationApi.
     */
    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        // The final argument to {@code requestLocationUpdates()} is a LocationListener
        // (http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationListener.html).
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

    /**
     * Removes location updates from the FusedLocationApi.
     */
    protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
        // It is a good practice to remove location requests when the activity is in a paused or
        // stopped state. Doing so helps battery performance and is especially
        // recommended in applications that request frequent location updates.

        // The final argument to {@code requestLocationUpdates()} is a LocationListener
        // (http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationListener.html).
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }

    /**
     * Updates the latitude, the longitude, and the last location time in the UI.
     */
    private void updateUI() {
        if (mCurrentLocation != null) {
            mLatitudeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude()));
            mLongitudeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()));
            mLastUpdateTimeTextView.setText(mLastUpdateTime);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(),
                    mCurrentLocation.getLongitude())).title("Marker"));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates fields based on data stored in the bundle.
     *
     * @param savedInstanceState The activity state saved in the Bundle.
     */
    private void updateValuesFromBundle(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // Update the value of mRequestingLocationUpdates from the Bundle, and make sure that
            // the Start Updates and Stop Updates buttons are correctly enabled or disabled.
            if (savedInstanceState.keySet().contains(REQUESTING_LOCATION_UPDATES_KEY)) {
                mRequestingLocationUpdates = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(
                        REQUESTING_LOCATION_UPDATES_KEY);
                setButtonsEnabledState();
            }

            // Update the value of mCurrentLocation from the Bundle and update the UI to show the
            // correct latitude and longitude.
            if (savedInstanceState.keySet().contains(LOCATION_KEY)) {
                // Since LOCATION_KEY was found in the Bundle, we can be sure that mCurrentLocation
                // is not null.
                mCurrentLocation = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(LOCATION_KEY);
            }

            // Update the value of mLastUpdateTime from the Bundle and update the UI.
            if (savedInstanceState.keySet().contains(LAST_UPDATED_TIME_STRING_KEY)) {
                mLastUpdateTime = savedInstanceState.getString(LAST_UPDATED_TIME_STRING_KEY);
            }
            updateUI();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer the **PolylineOptions** in developer document,

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/PolylineOptions

Here is sample code,

If you pass the list of LatLng values, you can draw a line on the map.

```
public void handleGetDirectionsResult(ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoints) {
        PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(15).color(Color.RED); //red color line & size=15
        Polyline routePolyline;
        for (int i = 0; i < directionPoints.size(); i++) {
            rectLine.add(directionPoints.get(i));
        }
        //clear the old line
        if (routePolyline != null) {
            routePolyline.remove();
        }
        // mMap is the Map Object
        routePolyline = mMap.addPolyline(rectLine);
}
```

Comment: should i create the handleGetDirectionsResult() function or i can implement the polyline under OnLocationChanged() function/method..because i don't have the handleGetDirectionsResult() in my code..?

Comment: its not default function. its user defined function. so you create it